# In React, how do you apply componentDidMount for this type of component?

Tags: reactjs, function, components, render

I have a React 16 application.  I have a component constructed like so ...

```
const AddressInput = (props) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const { disabled, error, location, onClear, placeholder, setLocation, showMap, value } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect 1 ...");
    if (value && placesRef?.current) {
      placesRef.current.setVal(value);

      if (zoom === 0) {
        setZoom(16);
      }
    }
  }, [placesRef, value, disabled, zoom]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect 2 ...");
    if (location) {
      if (zoom === 0) {
        setZoom(16);
      }
      if (location.lat !== position[0]) {
        setPosition([location.lat, location.lng]);
      }
    }
  }, [location, zoom, position]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect 3 ...");
    console.log("setting " + inputId + " to :" + placeholder);
    if (document.getElementById(inputId)) {
      document.getElementById(inputId).value = placeholder;
    }
  }, [])
    ...
  console.log("after use effect:");
  console.log(placeholder);

  return (
    <div style={error ? { border: "solid red" } : {}}>

    ...
    </div>
  );
};


export default AddressInput;
```

I would like to execute some code after the component has rendered.  Normally I could use componentDidMount, but I'm not sure how to apply that when the component is constructed like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a pure functional component you can use the `useEffect` hook (as of React v16.8) like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const AddressInput = (props) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const { disabled, error, location, onClear, placeholder, setLocation, showMap, value } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
     // your code here
  }, []) // empty array acts like `componentDidMount()` in a functional component
  return (
    <div style={error ? { border: "solid red" } : {}}>

    ...
    </div>
  );
};


export default AddressInput;
```

You can read more about `useEffect` here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: It's not working.  I edited my question to include what you have.  I had other "useEffect" statements in there, but actually none of them are getting called.  The only console.logs I see are the "after use effect:" message called after the useEffects are declared.  Am I implementing it the wya you suggest?

Comment: Please check your `package.json` and make sure you're using `react@16.8.0` and `react-dom@16.8.0` or later!